# Grep multiple string statements

Tags: r

In order to remove a specific string from multiple columns we must use this:

```
df1 <- with(df, df[ grepl( 'word1', df$Col1) | grepl( 'word1', df$Col2) | grepl( 'word1', df$Col3), ])
```

If we have more than one string like this:

```
df1 <- with(df, df[ grepl( 'word1', df$Col1) | grepl( 'word1', df$Col2) | grepl( 'word1', df$Col3), ])
df2 <- with(df, df[ grepl( 'word2', df$Col1) | grepl( 'word2', df$Col2) | grepl( 'word2', df$Col3), ])
```

How is it possible to have one call instead of many for 'word1; and 'word2' be into one ine?

Comment: Use `grepl( 'word1|word2', df$Col1)`

Comment: If you have more columns to span, you could try `df[rowSums(sapply(df[1:3], grepl, pattern="word1|word2")) > 0,]` where `[1:3]` could be any number of columns including `[c("Col1","Col2","Col3")]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need the combined regex. You can test it at https://regex101.com/ Then you can use `apply()` to run it on each column. This will yield a matrix of `TRUE` or `FALSE` values. 1 row per variable, 1 column per observation. You can `apply()` `any()` on that matrix to get the selection.

```
test <- apply(df, 2, grepl, pattern = "word1|word2")
df[apply(test, 2, any), ]
```